# List Name as string in c#

Tags: c#

I want to create a list of strings whose name should be the value of string variable.

Overall I want to assign a variable value to a (object) listname.

(Pseudo Code):

```
string s = "listname";
list<String>.Name = s;
```

Comment: I want to get value of varible and use it as name of list.

Answer (score 2):

Closest thing you can do is use a `Dictionary` to reference the variables.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> myLists = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

var s = "listname";
myLists.Add(s, new List<string>());

// To access
var list = myLists[s];
```

Comment: Should it not be `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`?